# Substitution function to parse path string

Tags: perl

I have a string:

```
$path='/home/usr/project/name'
```

I am trying to use the substitution function to parse the string and get just the name. My desired outcome is:

```
$path=name
```

I tried using with no success:

```
$path =~ s/^.+\///;
```

I'm not sure if the syntax is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) is a more portable solution than using `s///`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Basename qw(basename);

my $path = '/home/usr/project/name';
$path = basename($path);
print $path, "\n";
```

Output:

```
name
```

Comment: It's also not an experimental solution, as any newly crafted regular expression is likely to be.